# Conflict between xparse and pstricks: pstricks doesn't believe xparse function is defined

Tags: pstricks, latex3, xparse

I want to create a `pspicture` with a variety of parameters which are interdependent.  I'm using `expl3` for the interface.  But I get an error when I try to use `\getr`

```
Error: /undefined in \getr
Operand stack:
   --nostringval-- 56.9055  0.0
```

Initially, I had no ideas of where the error was arising from.  I've now tried quite a few different ways to replicate the error.  Most of them do **not** fail.  The only time I get a fail is when I'm using `xparse` to define the interface I want.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\psset{unit=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_eval:n {c}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\setr}{ m m }
        {
            \int_if_exist:cF { g__ace_angle_ #1 _int }
            { \int_new:c { g__ace_angle_ #1 _int }}
            \int_gset:cn  { g__ace_angle_ #1 _int }
                          {\int_eval:n {#2}}
        }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\getr}{ m }
        {
            \int_eval:c  { g__ace_angle_ #1 _int }
        }
    %%
    \setr{r1}{-30}
    \setr{u1}{\getr{r1}+90}
    %%
    \newcounter{dummy}\setcounter{dummy}{-30}
    \newcommand{\asimplecommand}{-30}
    \newcommand{\expliiimacro}{\int_eval:n {\asimplecommand + 60}}
    \newcommand{\argdependentmacro}[1]{\ifcase#1\relax-30\or0\or30\or60\fi}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\xparsemacroA}{ }{120}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\xparsemacroB}{ m }{#1}
    \cs_new:Npn \latexiiimacro #1 { #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{5ex}
\begin{document}

Works:\hspace*{1in}\texttt{getr(r1)=}$\getr{r1}$\newline
Works:\hspace*{1in}\texttt{getr(u1)=}$\getr{u1}$
\vspace{1cm}

\textbf{It's not a problem with passing a counter-like thingy:}\newline
Works:  
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\thedummy]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{It's not a problem with a command:}\newline
Works:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\asimplecommand]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{It's not with a command name whose internals are defined with \texttt{expl3}:}\newline
Works:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\expliiimacro]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{It's not a problem with first having to evaluate an argument:}\newline
Works:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\argdependentmacro{2}]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{It's not a problem with command name defined in \texttt{latex3}:}\newline
Works:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\latexiiimacro{-120}]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{What about \texttt{xparse}:}\newline
Fails:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\xparsemacroA]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\textbf{What about \texttt{xparse}:}\newline
Fails:
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\xparsemacroB{120}]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

Fails:
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}(0,1){u}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=\getr{r1}]{o}{r}[r1] 
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-60]{o}{r}[u1] 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

Of all the methods I'm using, only `xparse` seems to result in the error:

```
 Error: /undefined in \xparsemacro
```

That's actually the last place I thought I'd have a problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: Look for `\int_case:nnn` to be used instead of `\ifcase`: it's much more flexible and it's expandable as well.

Comment: Instead of `\int_if_exist:cF {...} { \int_new:c {...} }` I think you can use `\int_gzero_new:c {...}` which also sets the integer to zero if it is already defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is expandability. When you have

```
\pstRotation[RotAngle=\SomeMacro{argument}]{o}{r}[r1]
```

PStricks needs to be able to write the angle into the `.dvi` file, which is then used further down the line by PostScript. That works fine if `\SomeMacro` is expandable, as it gets turned into a number. However, if it is a protected (non-expandable) command then this will not work: instead the name of the command is written to the `.dvi` file, and this is then meaningless to PStricks.

LaTeX3 document commands are protected, as this makes most sense in almost all cases. There is, however, a method for creating expandable document commands

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getr}{ m }
   {
     \int_use:c  { g__ace_angle_ #1 _int }
  }
```

If you use this for all of the 'get' functions, you find that the example then does compile.

Comment: Wouldn't `\int_eval:n { \use:c {...} }` be better? The fact that the `c` variant works is a bit of an artifact, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Fixed: it should be `\int_use:c` as a variant on `\int_use:N` :-)