# A guide to understanding expandability: when to write protected functions and when not to

Tags: expansion, latex3

I'm having difficulty understanding (and *appreciating*) the concept of *expandability*.  I'm very murky about understanding  **when** and **how** expandability impacts me in writing code for my documents.

I've read [Why isn't everything expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable).  The answer was interesting and useful, but it didn't get at the heart of what I'm curious about.  I've also perused a number of the answers to other questions involving expandability:  of particular interest was [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/tricks-to-make-macros-expandable).

[In respondence to a recent question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95534/22413), it was explained that document commands are *protected* and hence not *expandable*.  Understanding this allowed me to write what I wanted and to get the effect I expected.

And [in a comment to another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94809/22413), it was explained how one should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` "when the function does unexpandable jobs such as setting token lists or sequences."

For years, I've been writing code like

```
\newcommand{\currentanswer}{}
\newcommand{\setcurrentanswer}[1]{\renewcommand{\currentanswer}{#1}}
```

knowing that after calling `\setcurrentanswer`, any call to `\currentanswer` will result in the desired output.  Am I relying upon (un)expandability here?  I'm not really sure; I only know that it does what I want.  Then there are times I know I can throw in a `\protect` to get the result I want: but, I really don't understand the **why** of it; I just know it gets the job done.

Recently, I've been trying to learn some LaTeX3:  the more I play with it, the more I like it.  LaTeX---which I always thought was pretty powerful---is suddenly much more powerful and transparent in the manner that macros and functions can be defined.  But now, I also seem to be running up against this issue of expandability, whereas before I could blithely go about my business ignorant of some of the subtlies of what I was doing.

While I am asking multiple questions here, I suspect that they really have much the same answer:  hence I'm not splitting them across multiple posts.

1. Could someone take the time to explain some of the nuances of expandability, or, if not, point me to a good reference?
2. How do I know when I'm working with a *protected* function/macro?
3. Is *protected* and *unexpandable* the same thing?
4. Could someone explain the preference for *protected* functions in LaTeX3?
5. And finally, apart from the answers to the above questions, why would it be preferrable to protect functions which perform unexpandable tasks:  such as setting tokens and sequences?  (I am *very interested* in understanding this last question.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An expandable command is one which can be converted 'fully' into its output inside a TeX `\edef` or `\write` (and a few other places). Thus for example

```
\def\testa{\testb}
\def\testb{\testc}
\def\testc{d}
\edef\teste{\testa}
\show\teste
```

will give

```
> \teste=macro:
->d.
```

*i.e.* all of the steps have been expanded, and we have just characters.

For text, this is nice and simple, but when you get TeX primitives involved things are more complex as some are expandable and some are not. Broadly, anything which performs an assignment is unexpandable. So if we have

```
\def\testa{\testb}
\def\testb{\testc}
\def\testc{\def\ARG{d}}
\def\ARG{}
\edef\teste{\testa}
\show\teste
```

we get

```
> \teste=macro:
->\def {d}.
```

Notice how the `\def` is left unchanged but the `\ARG` has vanished: it got expanded to what it is defined as (empty).

e-TeX allows us to define a *protected* macro. These do not expand inside an `\edef`, so

```
\def\testa{\testb}
\def\testb{\testc}
\def\testc{\def\NOTARG{d}}
\protected\def\NOTARG{}
\edef\teste{\testa}
\show\teste
```

now yields

```
> \teste=macro:
->\def \NOTARG {d}.
```

There is a subtle but important point here: `\def` is an unexpandable *primitive*, while `\NOTARG` is now a *protected* macro. You can tell that `\NOTARG` is protected using `\show`:

```
> \NOTARG=\protected macro:
->.
```

where the `\protected` tells us what we need to know. However, you have to *know* that `\def` is not expandable.

---

In the LaTeX3 documents, rather than expect people to learn the rules we've gone with a different approach: we document which functions are expandable (they are marked with a star). The reason everything else is then protected is that 'partial' expansion is a real issue. If you do

```
\def\testa{\let\testb\testc}
\edef\testb{\testa}
```

you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\testa ->\let \testb 
                     \testc
```

as `\let` is unaffected by the `\edef` but `\testb` is undefined. This gets worse when you look at 'real' documents, as the problem can be hidden many layers down.

Many of the issues people see in real LaTeX2e documents, for example where they forget `\protect` and have trouble, would be bypassed if most commands were protected. In general, you find a lot more (La)TeX code that is not expandable than code that is, so the position for LaTeX3 is that this is the exception, certainly for *document commands*. (Typesetting is not expandable, and that's what happens in documents.)

This leads us on to what I call the 'sheep and goats' approach to protected functions: all LaTeX3 code is either protected or fully expandable ['safe' (will give the expected result) inside `\edef`/`x`-type expansion], even if we are talking about auxiliary functions. The result is that we can always be sure if a function can be used in an expansion context: if it can, it's marked with a star, otherwise it will be protected and won't expand part way. So the 'correct' way to write LaTeX3 code is that if you use *anything* that is not expandable (*i.e.* not starred in the documentation) in your code, then you *have* to use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` or similar, and *not* `\cs_new:Npn`, *etc.*

Comment: Can you pls expand on "...all LaTeX3 code is either protected or expandable", seems obvious and the same can be said for LaTeX2e.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides My point is that that in the LaTeX2e case this is not the case: `\newcommand` for example cannot be used inside an `\edef` but is not protected either, so `\edef\demo{\newcommand{\noexpand\foo}{}}` will result in something unpleasant. I've edited to try to make this a little clearer.

Comment: @JosephWright: That is the same approach in ConTeXt MkIV. Any code that cannot be used inside an `\edef` is explicitly defined as unexpandable (using `\unexpanded\def...` where `\unexpanded` is ConTeXt's alias for `\protected`).

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for that: I'd not read the ConTeXt code in enough detail to pick that up. Obviously we've all come to the same conclusions :-)

Comment: Very nice job.  Your explanation makes me what to try to write something complex and subtle to see whether I really do get it.

Comment: Should a function that sets only local variables (`\tl_set:N\l@@_foo_tl{x}`) be declared by `\cs_new:Nn` or `\cs_new_protected:Nn`?

Answer (score 19):

in

```
\newcommand{\currentanswer}{}
\newcommand{\setcurrentanswer}[1]{\renewcommand{\currentanswer}{#1}}
```

your setting command is not expandable, it expands to `\renewcommand` which itself expands to some other things but ultimately it makes an *assignment* (with `\def`) it sets `\currentanswer` to the tokens passed in as `#1`. However the macro `\currentanswer`  ise defined to expand to the value passed in so is safe to use in an expansion context so long as the value passed in is safe.

Note as discussed in
[Advantages and disadvantages of fully expandable macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168)
It doesn't really make sense to categorize commands as expandable or not, any macro by definition expands to its definition, the differences come from the context, whether you are *only* doing expansion or whether you are in TeX's normal mode of operation with expansion interleaved with assignments and other non-expandable primitive operations.

1. Can try, but see also the above link
2. You need to look at its documentation or its definition. There are two distinct protection mechanisms LaTeX `\protect` system and the e-tex `\protected\def` system.

   ```
   *\show\pounds
   > \pounds=macro:
   ->\protect \pounds  .
   <*> \show\pounds

   ? 

   *\protected\edef\foo{abc}

   *\show\foo
   > \foo=\protected macro:
   ->abc.
   <*> \show\foo

   ?
   ```

   The above interactive session shows that `\pounds` is defined to be `\protect\pounds` (The second token there has a space at the end of its name) and so relies on LaTeX definition of `\protect`.

   `\foo` is defined using the e-TeX protection mechanism (which is what LaTeX3 commands use mostly) and this shows up in the `\show` output. The token `\foo` is protected by the tex engine itself (so will not expand in expansion only contexts) and does not need an internal macro to hold the real definition as is the case with `\pounds`.
3. No. Unexpandable primitives like `\def` work 'in the stomach', protected commands are  expandable macros, but you need them not to expand in some contexts (for example so they write to auxiliary file as the command name rather than its current definition) A protected command is normally expandable but acts as an unexpandable command in an expansion only context.
4. They are preferred as they lead to less surprises. (Normally).
5. An unprotected command will fail if used in a write or an `\edef` so for example in `\caption` where you need to write the text to the `.toc` file.

Comment: LaTeX3 code does not use `\protect` at all, so it's not 'mostly' e-TeX, it's all e-TeX :-)

Comment: @JosephWright yes I meant that the latex3 commands are mostly protected but you could defined unprotected ones when needed.

Comment: Thank you for directing to your other post.  Very enlightening.

Answer (score 15):

The entire topic of expandability requires some more-or-less steep learning curve.

This is a lengthy answer. Coming down to the point: I am trying to summarize the relevant essence of [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589) .

And given some good will, it requires knowledge of tools which show what is the actual outcome of your code.

The concept of expandability can be understood if you learn more about the involved internals, i.e. how to define macros *without* or *with* expanding the argument.

Putting it to the point: what is the outcome of `\renewcommand{\currentanswer}{\content}` ? Does `\currentanswer` expand to `\content` which, in turn, expands to whatever it "contains"? Or does `\currentanswer` contain a copy of "the value" of `\content` after the `\renewcommand`? The difference is, of course, only measurable if `\content` changes right after your `\renewcommand`.

Although this appears to be a technical distinction, it is directly related to your question.

What happens if you write `\section{\currentanswer}` if you modify the value of `\currentanswer` immediately after the `\section` command?

Another question is: what happens if you write `\section{\tikz \draw ... ;}` ? Clearly, this is a different use-case: we placed some *executable* code inside of the section argument.

The short answer is: you may need to learn the difference between `\def` and `\edef` ("expanded" `\def`). And you should know that `\section{}` uses `\edef` to collect its arguments; the same holds for other "movable" arguments (anything provided to sectioning commands, index, cross-references, etc) in LaTeX. The `\renewcommand` boils down to a `\def`; it does not expand the argument. Inside of the body of `\edef`, any conditionals will be expanded. Anything which is "executable" will *not* be expanded and needs to be protected. This is a rule-of-thumb; you would still need to learn what "executable" means. But typically, the intuition helps enough (like "a macro which contains a value is not expandable" whereas "`\tikz ... ;` certainly is").

Interesting helper utilities are `\show<macroname>` or `\message{The meaning of content is \meaning\content^^J}` to inspect what you wrote in your own code.

Furthermore, in LaTeX, any "executable" argument should be protected if you provide it as argument to some sectioning command. And protection typically means `\protect\macro`.

I suggest to read [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589) if you want to learn more about these concepts in general. It will probably help you to understand the related high-level concepts of LaTeX3.

Comment: The link you provided was very helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of TeX macros is from outside to inside. Therefore it is complicated to correctly write nesting macros in all the time.

With my [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, all functions are protected, but the evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside, just like `Lua` language. This would make programming with TeX much easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MathSquare { m } {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt { \IntEval {#1 * #1} }
  \Result { \Value \lTmpaInt }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\MathSquare{5}
\MathSquare{\MathSquare{5}}

\end{document}
```

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Result` command.

> when to write protected functions and when not to

In my opinion, **ALL** user-defined functions should be protected and only their return values (as `tl` variables) could be expandable. And this package would help users to fulfil it.

```
\TlSet \lTmpaTl {\MathSquare{5}}
\TlLog {\Value \lTmpaTl}
```

In the above example, `\MathSquare` function is protected, and its return value is stored in `\lTmpaTl` variable, which could be expandable.

Comment: Good effort, but this may be a bit... overkill somehow? Also there's some leaky abstraction here, you can't write things like IntEval{\MathSquare{5}*5}

Comment: Also what about just telling these "normal users" to use Lua and program in that instead? (providing some good interface)

Comment: It's a bit absurd that you keep the "mutate" / specify target" style though. Like TlConcat or TlPutLeft / TlReplaceAll etc. could just return the result.

Comment: @user202729 It is possible to make `\IntEval` parse math expression in the future. Not everyone likes to use `Lua` language. In most programming languages, assingments don't have return values.

Comment: I mean why don't you just make it so that you do TlSet \a {\TlConcat \b \c}. // Problem is, if they don't like normal programming language in the first place, why don't we just write a proper "programming in TeX" tutorial instead of making this wrapper thing. //

Comment: I agree that being able to conveniently nest function inside another is good though instead of having to write in assembly-like syntax and use temp variables.  // By the way, does this support storing *expandable* things in TL variables? It claims to expands the argument in all cases. // Any relative performance impact comparison?

Comment: @user202729 You are right that it would be better to make `\TlConcat` return the result. I means that not everyone likes to mix TeX and Lua in one document although I think most users like modern programming languages more than TeX.

Comment: @user202729 Variables in `functional` package are the same as those in `expl3`. The packages just evaluates the arguments of functions if those arguments start wtih known functions.

Comment: The approach is somewhat comparable to pgfmathparse... pgfmathresult I guess, but there's more "magic" here and maybe when there's leaky abstraction it might be harder to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is an answer to my original question.  At best this seems to be a work around, which i haven't tested yet.  The thrust of my question was about the emphasis on *protected* in LaTeX3 and how *protected* differs from *unexpandable*.  Your answer doesn't address these issues.

Comment: @A.Ellett Maybe I should state my opionion directly: ALL user defined functions should be protected and only their return values (as tl variables) could be expandable.

Comment: @A.Ellett I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional note on how to write expl3 code regarding expandability.

---

Recall that

- a function is called "expandable" if it works *as you desire* in expansion-only context.
- within the unexpandable ones, the ones that

  - does not error out in expansion-only context, and
  - does the right thing when it's eventually executed in normal context

  are called *robust*. The rest are called "fragile".
- you should protect the unexpandable functions because otherwise it may be fragile, and fragile commands
  does the **wrong thing** when you accidentally/need to put it in expansion-only context (e.g. moving argument).

---

Imagine you want to do something like (pseudocode in C-like syntax)

```
result = f(g(h(argument)))
```

where `argument` and `result` are variables, `f`, `g`, `h` are functions that *should* return some result.

If all of them are expandable, you can simply do

```
\tl_set:Ne \result { \f:e { \g:e { \h:e { \argument } } } }
```

However, what if some are not expandable? Obviously you can't just pass it inside the argument, there's **no way** for the outer macro to access the result.

The common TeX idiom here is that **the function stores the result into somewhere**.

In expl3 code, the destination is usually provided as a N-type argument. (compare with pgf, math result are stored in `\pgfmathresult`)

Assume `f` is not expandable, it would normally have the form

```
\f:Nn <target> <argument>
```

or

```
\f:N <data>   % for example regex_replace_all
```

In such cases you would need to "unroll" the call chain:

```
\h:Ne \result {\argument}
\g:Ne \result {\result}
\f:Ne \result {\result}
```