# How to check if optional argument has its default value?

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

Is it possible to check whether some macro's optional argument has its default value and generate different output based on this condition?

For instance, say I defined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{item}[section]
\newcommand{\myitem}[1][the default]{\refstepcounter{item}Item{{~\theitem}}: This is #1.\newline}

\begin{document}

\section{Default Item}

\myitem

\section{Special Items}

\myitem[special case 1]
\myitem[special case 2]

\end{document}
```

How can I have the counter in double curly braces only be output if the argument is not its default value? Specifically, I would like to remove the counter only from the single item in the first section in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{item}[section]
\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{o}{%
  \par\noindent
  \refstepcounter{item}%
  Item\IfValueT{#1}{~\theitem}: %
  This is \IfNoValueTF{#1}{the default}{#1}.\par
}

\begin{document}

\section{Default Item}

\myitem

\section{Special Items}

\myitem[special case 1]
\myitem[special case 2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way (unless jumping into `latex.ltx` and tracking the `\@xargdef` etc. definitions)

First define the default argument as macro outside of `\myitem` and inside of `\myitem` check by `\ifx\@temp@\myitemdefault` (say).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{item}[section]

\makeatletter
\def\myitemdefault{the default}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1][\myitemdefault]{%
  \edef\@temp@{#1}
  \ifx\myitemdefault\@temp@%
  This is the default stuff!%
  \else
  \refstepcounter{item}Item{{~\theitem}}: This is #1.%

  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Default Item}

\myitem

\section{Special Items}

\myitem[special case 1]
\myitem[special case 2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this have any restrictions? Will it also work if `the default` is itself a macro?

Comment: It won't work with unexpandable content in a macro

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. In the case at hand, `\myitemdefault` is actually defined as `\def\uclinebackspace{\vspace{-\dimexpr\parskip+\baselineskip}}`. After reading [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/a-guide-to-understanding-expandability-when-to-write-protected-functions-and-wh) I'm not certain I understand. Is there something I can do with `\protected` to still make this work?